# How does OpenStreetmap handle concurrent edits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openstreetmap

How does OSM deal with concurrent edits? For example, is there an algorithm or hardcoded constrains when two users try to edit the same geometry?

Comment: I don't see how this is Rails related. Unless you're providing context on what you want to do in your app, or any code, you should remove the tag.

Comment: Because the OSM API itself is based on RAILS. In my opinion it is thus not unrelated, since some of the concurrency features might be based on algorithms and features provided by the platform. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/The_Rails_Port

Comment: yes, but your question is not about how to X thing on Rails, it's about the specific implementation of OSM, hence the tag is misplaced. I'd suggest asking in their mailing list or opening an issue on their repo: https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website

Answer (score 2):

OSM API doesn't avoid nor solve editing conflicts if different contributors alter the same object during the same timeperiod. Users get notified and need to solve it manually:

- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners_Guide_1.4.2#How_to_avoid_conflicts_.28optional.29
- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Basic_editing#Possible_conflicts_during_edit

This is pretty similar how VCS deal with the problem.